# SSIS package fails if not executed inside SSIS server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ssis

I'm not able to resolve this problem:
I have a SSIS package deployed in SSIS catalog.
I created a stored procedure to assign parameters and run the package (using SSISDB.catalog.create_execution, SSISDB.catalog.set_execution_parameter_value,  SSISDB.catalog.start_execution).

If I exec procedure from SSMS (logged with my personal account) everything works fine.
If I exec same procedure with same parameter from a net core web api the package fails.
The web api is deployed on iis server and relative application pool runs using my personal account as identity (same used to exec procedure from ssms).
The error is about the access to network file (\\servername\sharedfolder\nomefile.csv). The package can't access the file because it's open from another user or i have no permission.

If i open the report overview of failed and succeeded execution they are identical.
Same parameters, same caller, same machine. The only differences are in execution time and final status.

To try to understand the problem I've also given everyone read and write permission on shared folder, but it didn't change the process result.

*EDIT: I tried to exec procedure from SSMS on a different machine and it fails.
So if I use SSMS on machine where is installed SSIS it works, from other machine it fails, even if I'm using windows authentication in both of cases.*

Comment: Kerberos double hop issue is my guess

Comment: Are you running SSMS on the SQL Server?  Can you just create a SQL Agent job with a proxy to run the package?  That would give you a locally-logged-on  identity to run the package.

Comment: Otherwise, as David points out, the easier way will be to use a credentialed user from an agent job (assuming execution parameters are not dynamic) and then you call `sp_start_job`.

Comment: My suspicion would be double hop as well, @billinkc , but then I would expect the OP the get the same error when executing the package from SSMS as that would normally result in a double hop as well. Unless I recall incorrectly though, I don't think SSIS gives that error on a double hop, I feel like it has an error stating it's unable to find the file or doesn't have permission where as this states that the file might be open by someone else; implying a write error rather than a read error.

Comment: Nevermind, the edit confirms double hop! Ignore me then. :)

Comment: exec form procedure give me the advantage of multiple execution at same time, and it is simpler to pass parameters. If don't find any other solution I will try to use job

Comment: Anything you can do in an SSIS package can also be done in a Stored Procedure. Consider rewriting the SSIS package as one or more stored procedures and calling them from a SQL Agent Job. In almost every case this results in much more predictable and supportable behaviour in SQL Server